# Store large amount of data and access it when needed

Tags: c#, python, c, storage

I need to store some data which is a float number and epoch of current time (frequency is 1 second but might be higher in future). I need to do this for long periods of time, might even be years and then I need to access it by date. Ex: Let's assume I've stored 1 year worth of data now I need to know the value of this float number when epoch was `X`.

My first thought was to divide this data in directories, ex `Dir Year-2017, Month-02, Day-08`. And I was wondering what would be the best approach. Which language is more suited for this kind of thing? I mainly use [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but I can code in other languages too.

I'm not looking for code snippets directly ( although if you want to put them they're highly appreciated ) but where can I learn to do so?

Comment: store the data in a database such as mySQL or sqlite3

Comment: ever heard of a database?

Comment: Yes, I've heard of databases. I was wondering if a DB would still be the optimal choice considering I have to store 150 numbers each second, and the frequency might be higher in the future and if I would end up needing to store 1000 numbers each second would a DB still be the best choice considering this might go on for years?

Comment: Have a look at http://db-engines.com/en/article/Time+Series+DBMS - some databases are designed for this sort of thing. Some (like rrdtool) manage storage by degrading resolution for older data.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this would be to store the data in a database such as SQL, with each entry containing your float, your epoch number and any other meta data you want to include.

sqlite3 is an easy python API to create and add to databases. loads of tutorials online too ;)

Comment: Is it good even if I need to store more numbers? I mean I have a stream of 150 numbers to store each second ( and I might need to store it at higher frequency in the future) , for the whole day, and this will go on for years, wouldn't the DB get too lengthy?

Comment: No it will be fine. You can of course structure the database in a certain way that one entry pertains to one day? one hour? The structure is where database efficiency and elegance comes in, but depending on who you will want to use it you should design it well. if you are going to store all these figures they will become "lengthy" on one way or another?

Comment: You can also look at apache Hive but again its just another data warehousing tool